# How does google get the movies showtimes?

Tags: web-scraping

I'm really amazed how Google provides the showtimes of all the current movies in my country (Argentina)! I was about to start a project related to this, and needed that info so I thought to scrap all the cinemas websites of my city... but then I just asked my self how does google do this? I mean their algorithms are so good that they can tell if the site is a cinema site or not, and they can grab the info they need all automatically?

Does anyone know any good book or site to read about this? I mean how to do an "smart scrapping"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how they get the data, maybe really smart scrapers but for your other question:

http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html